# Homemade salt water taffy

Tags: candy, taffy

Are there any techniques to aerate homemade taffy, particularly saltwater taffy.

The professional saltwater taffy makers in Atlantic City, NJ and Ocean City, NJ use machines that pull the taffy over and over. But they are making massive quantities at a time.

I need a tip, trick, hack or technique that would do the same thing, but on a smaller scale.

Comment: @RonBeyer I would say that qualifies as an answer.  If you post one and ping me here, I'll come back and upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To manually pull taffy, either you can stretch out the taffy between your arms by gripping one end of the taffy with each hand and extending your arms. This is extremely strenuous, and a lot of work especially when the taffy is cold or when starting.

Another option is to get a Taffy Hook, which looks like this:

[image]

It doesn't have to be anything specialized, any stainless-steel hook you can mount on the wall or temporarily attach to a surface will suffice. The idea is to hook the taffy on the loop and pull towards you or the ground, re-loop and repeat until the taffy is the desired consistency.

There are a number of home contraptions in various price ranges that work either by a motorized system or a hand-crank:

[Youtube video of a hand-crank taffy puller](https://youtu.be/tNsYoPdSpBk)

There are even homemade [taffy pullers that you can find by searching the internet](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/using-math-build-ultimate-taffy-machine-180960849/) if you are more mechanically inclined.

Comment: All correct, although from personal experience I can say that pulling small amounts (a pound or less) of hot taffy at home is not that strenuous.  Taffy hooks and machines are better for larger batches.

Comment: @Guildenstern Yeah, I'd say for 1lb batch or something it would be easier to do by hand, unless you had some kind of arthritis or joint issue, the hook or hand-machine may be the way to go for larger batches.

Comment: I was going to make 5 lbs.